# How to show most recently updated restock product in database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I'm currently hand coding a eCommerce website. In the index page, it would show the recently updated restock product.
ex:
I restocked the available product in my admin panel, now in the index page it will have an area where it would show this item has been restocked.

I added a field with 'last_updated' in my database then using the php with current time function and MySQL query ("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY lasted_updated DESC LIMIT 5") but the problem here is that every minor update such as replacing of images would also get queried in it.

my table: products

- pid | int(11)
- pname | varchar(80)
- detail | text
- price | varchar(5)
- category | varchar(20)
- sub-category | varchar(20)
- stock | int(11)
- date_added | date
- last_updated | time

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to make that column in your table just be a DATETIME or INT11 field.  Do not "auto-update" it for every time it's queried.

Instead, add a line to your "stock update" function that does something like this:

```
<?php

$timeNow = time();

$query = "  UPDATE  products 
                    SET     lasted_updated = $timeNow,
                            quantity = $newQuantity
                    WHERE   id = $itemID";

?>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for this late comment and thanks for your assistance though i still need to query it properly in my index page

Answer (score 0):

I find it's easiest to maintain a timestamped write-only transaction journal for all such accounting-type transactions also identifying the user who did it. Then you have the basis for a complete audit trail as well.